# Creating a table From a join or addin a column in a table depending on the first table

Tags: sql, sql-server

so i have a table 
Reference(IDvalue,Symbol) 
and 
History(symbol,etc..)
 i want to add a column that contains the ID value int History based on the join of 
reference.Symbol=History.Symbol

i want to have like if the symbol is ADD and it has IDValue=2
My history table must contain that Idvalue

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your attempts, will greatly help us help you here.

Comment: Im looking for the way i havent tried anything cause i didnt know how to

Comment: That doesn't help us help you though.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Would creating a view be a viable solution for you? Something like this...

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT R.IDValue AS RIDVAlue, R.Symbol AS RSymbol, H.Symbol AS HSymbol, H.IDValue AS HIDValue 
FROM Reference R 
LEFT OUTER JOIN History H ON H.Symbol = R.Symbol
```

Info on view creation: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp